# Add a colored text in italic to Highchart plot

Tags: html, highcharts, r-highcharter

I want to add a text in italic with blue color using HTML. I used the `<em>` tag to define italic text and the `<span>` tag to define a color but i only get the text in italic :
[image]

This what i did :

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
highchart()%>%
  hc_yAxis(
    title = list(text = "value")
  )%>%
  hc_xAxis(
    accessibility = list(
      rangeDescription = 0:5
    )
  )%>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
      labels = list(
        connectorAllowed = FALSE
      ),
      pointStart = 0
    )
  )%>%
  hc_series(
    list(
      type = "spline",
      color = "#0000FF",
      name = 'data',
      data = c(100,92,84,77,71)
    )
    
  )%>%
  hc_labels(
    items = list(
      list(
        html = "<span style=\"color:#0000FF\"><em>a text here in blue color</em></span>",
        style = list(
          left = "144%",
          top = "50%"
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: `html = "<span style='color:#0000FF'><em>a text here in blue color</em></span>"`

Comment: @A.Meshu i remplace my code by yours but its does'nt work, i still got text in italic with no blue color

Comment: @Johnjohn why can't you do it this way?  hc_labels(
    items = list(
      list(
        html = "<em>a text here in blue color</em>",
        style = list(
          color = "#0000FF",
          left = "144%",
          top = "50%"
        )
      )
    )
  )

Comment: @madepiet thank you, it works. I post the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to put tag inside `list` objet. This is the full code :

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)
highchart()%>%
  hc_yAxis(
    title = list(text = "value")
  )%>%
  hc_xAxis(
    accessibility = list(
      rangeDescription = 0:5
    )
  )%>%
  hc_plotOptions(
    series = list(
      labels = list(
        connectorAllowed = FALSE
      ),
      pointStart = 0
    )
  )%>%
  hc_series(
    list(
      type = "spline",
      color = "#0000FF",
      name = 'data',
      data = c(100,92,84,77,71)
    )
    
  )%>%
  hc_labels(items = list(
    list(html = "<em>a text here in blue color</em>", style = list( color = "#0000FF", left = "144%", top = "50%" ))
    ))
```